# Selecting float number from FLOAT() column with PHP and mysqli

Tags: php, floating-point, mysqli, bind-variables

Good day. I have a problem with selecting float number from MySQL database using bind variables of `mysqli` class.

The type of `price` column is `FLOAT(9,2)` and it's value `1.01`

Simplified piece of code:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT price FROM goods WHERE id=5');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result(&$price);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $price;
// 1.0099999904633
```

As I understood `mysqli` automatically casts it to double. But why?

When I change type of column in table to `DOUBLE(9,2)` everything goes fine and the `$price` value is exactly `1.01`.

Is there any way to obtain `1.01` value in `$price` variable having `FLOAT(9,2)` as column type (without rounding functions)?

Thank you.

Comment: It's always advisable to use DECIMAL rather than FLOAT when working with monetary values, becaue this helps prevent those little rounding errors that occur with floats in any language - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems or even to store the value as integer cents rather than decimal dollars

Comment: 1.01 cannot be represented as a floating point number exactly. As you see, the nearest you can come is 1.0099999.... If you're storing money values in the database, don't use floats. Use a DECIMAL type, or an int and convert your dollar/cents values to just cents.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> 1.01 cannot be represented as a floating point number exactly. As you see, the nearest you can come is 1.0099999.... If you're storing money values in the database, don't use floats. Use a DECIMAL type, or an int and convert your dollar/cents values to just cents